# exitStateAction not working as expected on MySQL INNODB Cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysql-innodb-cluster

I'm in the process of setting up and testing an `Innodb Cluster`. So far I have three nodes running 8.0.27 and two routers all working fine.

I now want to test what happens if the network connection suddenly dissapears on one.

I have all three nodes set up with:

```
"autoRejoinTries", "3"
"exitStateAction","OFFLINE_MODE"
"expelTimeout":"5"
```

So when I remove the network connection from node 3 using:

```
ifdown eth0
```

I see that it disapears from the cluster and shows as:

```
"status": "UNREACHABLE",
```

and on the server itself it says:

```
"Cluster has no quorum and cannot process write transactions: Group has no quorum"
```

But I was expecting that the database would go into `offline_mode`. But when I check, it still says it is off:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.offline_mode;
+-----------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.offline_mode |
+-----------------------+
|                     0 |
+-----------------------+
```

Have I missed something, or misunderstood what `"exitStateAction","OFFLINE_MODE"` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it was because of the `autoRejoinTries` value.

Basically, assuming a value of three, it does:

- Network Fails
- 5 seconds passes
- a “suspicion” that a problem has occurred happens on all nodes
- 5 seconds passes to see if the node re-appears (`expel_timeout`)
- Node is expelled from the cluster
- try and connect (1)
- wait 5 minutes
- try and connect (2)
- wait 5 minutes
- try and connect (3)
- execute exitStateAction

In other words, you have to wait for 10 minutes before it goes into `OFFLINE_MODE`.
Setting `autoRejoinTries` to 0 or 1 has the desired affect of making it go into `OFFLINE_MODE` straight away. Of course, it then doesn't try and reconnect automatically, which is a pain if you have a very brief outage.

I guess in light of the fact one of the options is `ABORT_SERVER` e.g. shutdown MySQL, it does make sense.